# Ruby $stdin.gets without showing chars on screen

Tags: ruby

I want to ask users to type in a password, but I don't want the chars to appear on screen as they type.

How do I do this in Ruby?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a gem for such user interaction: [highline](https://rubygems.org/gems/highline).

```
password = ask("Password:  ") { |q| q.echo = false }
```

Or even:

```
password = ask("Password:  ") { |q| q.echo = "*" }
```

Comment: What if the user's terminal does not have a black background?

Comment: its only for an in-house script, so its not an issue :) good to point out for others though

Answer (score 38):

You can use the [STDIN.noecho](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/io/console/rdoc/IO.html#method-i-noecho) method from the IO/console module:

```
require 'io/console'
pw = STDIN.noecho(&:gets).chomp
```

Comment: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'noecho' for #<IO:<STDIN>>` on `ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin15]`

Comment: `require 'io/console'`

Comment: This is the winner.

Answer (score 24):

If you're on a system with `stty`:

```
`stty -echo`
print "Password: "
pw = gets.chomp
`stty echo`
puts ""
```

Comment: No gems please, I like this answer ;-)

Answer (score 6):

You want to make sure your code is idempotent... other solutions listed here assume you want to exit this chunk of functionality with echo turned back on. Well, what if it was turned off before entering the code, and it's expected to stay off?

```
stty_settings = %x[stty -g]
print 'Password: '

begin
  %x[stty -echo]
  password = gets
ensure
  %x[stty #{stty_settings}]
end

puts

print 'regular info: '
regular_info = gets

puts "password: #{password}"
puts "regular:  #{regular_info}"
```

Answer (score 2):

This is solution for **UNIX systems**:

```
  begin
    system "stty -echo"
    print "Password: "; pass1 = $stdin.gets.chomp; puts "\n"
    print "Password (repeat): "; pass2 = $stdin.gets.chomp; puts "\n"
    if pass1 == pass2
      # DO YOUR WORK HERE
    else
      STDERR.puts "Passwords do not match!"
    end
  ensure
    system "stty echo"
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar answer as glenn but more complete: http://dmathieu.com/articles/development/ruby-console-ask-for-a-password/